# Android - Retrieving current location with android gps provider in onClick()

Tags: android, gps, location, location-provider

I'm trying to make a trivial application in which the user clicks a button and a few text views display various information about the phone(model,battery %,location,signal strength etc). I'm having trouble getting the current latitude and longitude, since when I press the button the textview displays the previous latitude/longitude(first time it shows 0,0 and the second the position I was when I first pressed it).

What I'm trying to achieve is when I press the button, activate the location manager and location listener, and make the onClick() method wait until the latitude is not equal to the old latitude. I've tried Threads, handler, and asynctask but I haven't managed anything. Any tips? This is how my onClick() method looks right now: (Infogatherer is a class where I collect all the info)

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bMeasurements:

        oldLat=InfoGatherer.getLatitude();
        oldLong=InfoGatherer.getLongitude();

            //SOMEWHERE HERE START A THREAD OR SOMETHING IN ORDER TO RETRIEVE CURRENT LOCATION
        //Retrieval and Assignment of information to the corresponding text fields
        DeviceName.setText(infogatherer.getDeviceName());

        NetworkOp.setText(infogatherer.getNetworkOp());

        Date.setText(infogatherer.getDate());

        BatteryStatus.setText(String.valueOf(infogatherer.getBatteryStatus()));

        Generation.setText(String.valueOf(infogatherer.getGeneration()));   
        infogatherer.getLocation();
        Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
        infogatherer.getSignalStrength();
        SignalStrength.setText(String.valueOf(infogatherer.getDbm()));

        oldLat = InfoGatherer.getLatitude();
        oldLong = InfoGatherer.getLongitude();
        break;

    }
```

This is my InfoGatherer class:

```
package com.example.netmap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.CellInfoGsm;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthGsm;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;

public class InfoGatherer extends Application{

    String address,city,country;
    int cid,lac,generation=0,ipAddress=0,signalStrngth=0;
    private GsmCellLocation location;
    private WifiInfo wifiInfo;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener ll;
    Geocoder geoc;
    static public double Longitude,Latitude=0;
    List<Address> addresses;
    Context context;
    Intent batteryIntent;
    TelephonyManager tm;
    WifiManager wifimanager;

    public InfoGatherer(){

    }
    public InfoGatherer(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getDate(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        return Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"-"+Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))+"-"+Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"    "+Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }

    public String getDeviceName(){
        return Build.MANUFACTURER +" "+Build.MODEL;
    }

    public String getNetworkOp(){
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getNetworkOperatorName();

    }

    public float getBatteryStatus() {
        batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        return ((float)batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) / (float)batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)) * 100.0f;
    }


    public int getGeneration(){
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getNetworkType();
    }

     public int getCid(){
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        location = (GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();
        return location.getCid();
    }

    public int getLac(){
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        location = (GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();
        return location.getLac();
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiInfo = wifimanager.getConnectionInfo();
        ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",(ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
    }

    public void getLocation(){
        /*Criteria c = new Criteria();
        c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);*/

        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ll = new mylocationlistener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

    }

    public class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(location!=null){
                Longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Latitude = location.getLatitude();

                lm.removeUpdates(ll);

            }

        }



        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Pass views as parameters? DIscuss
            //DeviceName.setText(String.valueOf(Latitude) +" "+String.valueOf(Longitude));

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void getSignalStrength(){
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener Listener = new phoneStateListener();
        tm.listen(Listener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

    public class phoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
                signalStrngth = -113 + 2 * signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();

            }
            else
                signalStrngth = -113 + 2 * signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
        }

    }





    static public double getLatitude(){
        return Latitude;
    }

    static public double getLongitude(){
        return Longitude;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }

    public int getDbm(){
        return signalStrngth;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your `InfoGatherer` class

Comment: Why did you removeUpdates at `onLocationChanged`? Try without that line

Comment: I'm removing updates because if I don't then the gps provider isn't disabled when it finds longitude/latitude. I tried again without that line and there's still the same problem: when I first press the button I get 0 latitude and 0 longitude and the next time I get the previous locations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used AsyncTask, which helped me in order to sleep the app while I looked for the location.

```
private class LocationThread extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        infogatherer.startLocationListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
        while (!infogatherer.getGo()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        //Do whatever you wanna do after you get location
    }
}
```

getGo is a boolean which whenever becomes true gives the location back

```
public class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        if(location != null){
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(ll);
            go = true;
        }
    }
```

hope you understand the procedure. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t provide enough time to Location service get the location.
You ask for latitude and longitude before the `LocationManager` have time to call `onLocationChanged`.

```
infogatherer.getLocation();
Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
```

Call `infogatherer.getLocation();` out of onClick event. Do that at Activity `onResume()` event.
Remove `lm.removeUpdates(ll);` from `onLocationChanged`. Call it at Activity `onPause()`event.

If you want see this example how to create a [GPS Manager Class](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

**EDIT**
Try something like this: **Note:** Not tested!

```
private void updateLocationText(double oldLat, double oldLong) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            boolean isPositionChanged = false;
            double lat;
            double long;
            while (!isPositionChanged) {  
                lat = InfoGatherer.getLatitude();
                long = InfoGatherer.getLongitude();
                if(lat != oldLat || long != oldLong)isPositionChanged = true;
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

**Note that if you click on the button without having been no change of location, it will run forever.**

**EDIT AGAIN**

Another approach more clean:

Replace

```
Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
```

with this

```
Location.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
        Location.postInvalidate();//Try without, may be not necessary
    }
}, 3000);//Change if need
```

Comment: That would only sort of work - you are assuming the Activity won't be remaining in the foreground during a substantial change of position.  Best would be to trigger a delayed update process, either displaying a busy icon or the old value (possibly shaded to indicate it is old) in the meantime.

Comment: I think chris is right,could you go a little bit deeper in how you would trigger a delayed update process ?

Comment: ramaral,thanks for all the edits. The last one seems to work, although depending on where the user is (indoors,outdoors etc) it takes longer for the longitude and latitude to be extracted. So I just can't tell the program "wait for 4-5 seconds" , i want it to be more adjustable and to see when the values change and then release the thread :)

Comment: If you only use this `LocationListener` to update Location TextView then update it in `onLocationChanged`

Comment: no the same time i update the textview i want to send a packet to a server as well. So I need to wait until everything is complete :/

Comment: Use what i suggested in my other answer. You can do anything you want inside onLocationChanged

Answer (score 0):

Create the LocationListener out of Aplication.
In the Ativity instantiate the class, override the onLocationChanged event and update Location TextView there.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .........
    .........
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new MyLocationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
            if(location!=null){
                Location.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLatitude()));
                lm.removeUpdates(listener);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In onClick() event replace:

```
infogatherer.getLocation();
Location.setText(String.valueOf(InfoGatherer.getLatitude()+","+InfoGatherer.getLatitude()));
```

with

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

Comment: In the activity where you have the Location TextView and the button to get current lat and long